# Define an interface as having all the keys of a given object

Tags: typescript

I'm writing some code that looks like this:

```
interface Config {
  [key: string]: number;
}

interface Foo {
  value: number;
}

interface ConfiguredObject {
  [key: string]: Foo;
}

function createConfiguredObject(config: Config): ConfiguredObject {
  return Object.entries(config).reduce((acc, cur) => {
    return {
      ...acc,
      [cur[0]]: {
        value: cur[1] * 10
      }
    };
  }, {});
}

const myObject = createConfiguredObject({
  foo: 1,
  bar: 2
});

console.log(myObject.foo.value); //No warning
console.log(myObject.charlie.value); //No warning, but will throw an error
console.log(myObject.foo.aaa); //'Property 'aaa' does not exist on type 'Foo'.ts(2339)'
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-taussig-88try

That is - I want to pass a `Config` object into a function, and then have that function return an object with matching keys, and some kinds of values.

The issue I have with what I currently have, is that typescript won't warn me if I try access a key that doesn't exist (in the `myObject.charlie` example).

How would I change my code to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
interface Config {
  [key: string]: number;
}

interface Foo {
  value: number;
}

type ConfiguredObject<T> = {
  [key in keyof T]: Foo;
}

function createConfiguredObject<T extends Config>(config: T): ConfiguredObject<T> {
  return Object.entries(config).reduce((acc, cur) => {
    return {
      ...acc,
      [cur[0]]: {
        value: cur[1] * 10
      }
    };
  }, {} as ConfiguredObject<T>);
}

const myObject = createConfiguredObject({
  foo: 1,
  bar: 2
});

console.log(myObject.foo.value); //No warning
console.log(myObject.charlie.value); //Property 'charlie' does not exist on type 'ConfiguredObject<{ foo: number; bar: number; }>'.
console.log(myObject.foo.aaa); //'Property 'aaa' does not exist on type 'Foo'.ts(2339)'
```

hope this can help you